# I'm looking for a fiction novel series about a submarine, being the USS Seawolf, finding the world in flames after a nuclear war.

Tags: story-identification, novel, post-apocalyptic

The first book in the series has the submarine returning to San Francisco, battling some white clothed people, and then taking off at the end of the novel to look for survivors. There is the added mystery of another submarine, which runs quieter than the Seawolf. The Seawolf has a blue-green laser than can be used like a radar, as well as a weapons system. The obvious lead character is the captain of the ship, there is a female lead, a researcher in San Francisco who joins the sub at the end. Despite all these details, I'm not able to find the book!!!!

Comment: How certain are you that the sub was called the Seawolf?

Comment: Pretty certain - but I did read this book about 20 years ago, so there may be some bias in that!! From what I recall, it should be the Seawolf, considering I was heavily vested in reading about submarines around that time!

Comment: It could be The Last Ship which is a TV series now too, Rhona Mitra plays the female scientist.

Comment: No, not that either. But the series is what reminded me of the book and why I'm getting twisted trying to find it.

Comment: This series - http://www.amazon.com/Michael-DiMercurio/e/B000APMASA/ref=dp_byline_cont_book_1?

Answer (score 8):

This is likely to be **On the Beach**, sort of. Or an enormous rip-off thereof.

This was a 1957 novel by mainstream author Nevil Shute. It was made into a major film (Gregory Peck as the submarine captain) and remade in 2000 as a TV film.

What is similar is:

The submarine is running further and further south in the Pacific to find surviving people. A nuclear war in the northern hemisphere has produced a radioactive cloud which is remorselessly spreading south.

The submarine visits San Francisco (but everyone is dead there).

The submarine's name is USS Scorpion. In the novel there is one other surviving submarine, USS Swordfish in the Atlantic, which sends a couple of messages but is otherwise not involved in the plot.

Nothing else matches but there may be a reason for that:

Wikipedia says that it originally appeared as a 4-part series **The Last Days on Earth** in a British newspaper and was rewritten for the novel. This original series would be pretty inaccessible now but it would be my guess that you have read some reprinted form of this.

Comment: Downvoted. As you say, only the submarine really fits the description. Everything else is a complete mismatch.

Comment: Actually I was about to add that I may be confusing the film and the novel here. I don't have immediate access to the differences. Are you saying the original series is a mismatch?

Comment: I stand ready to upvote if you can show any evidence that the original series was closer to OPs description, especially the presence of the second submarine or the laser weapon system.

Comment: @Richard Those would be convincing but cannot do.This has to be obscure or someone else would have answered by now. However: (1) OP was looking for a series - this was a series (2) (trivial) in novel/film lead character was sub captain, who had a romantic interest (3) sub was Scorpion in novel and Sawfish in film so imagining Seawolf in series is no stretch. I'll leave it to OP now to see if title rings a bell.

Comment: Hey guys... Sorry @eastkitton, I know it wasn't On The Beach - one of my all-time favorites btw. The novel I'm looking for may be a rip-off, but I know it's not that book. The one I'm looking for would be based in the 90s.

Comment: Not a bad attempt, @eastkitton, and look on the brigh side... you still got points out of it.

Comment: This was the first thing I thought of too, because they do go to San Francisco which is kind of unique. I love post apocalypse fiction, I read everything I can find and that's the only time I ever remember San Francisco featuring in that kind of story when the story wasn't either about or actually set in San Francisco.

Answer (score 5):

Try the Omega Sub series about the U.S.S Liberator by author J.D. Cameron.  Book 5 called "Death Dive" deals with people in white shirts.

[image]

---

### Blurb

> On the East Coast of a nuclear-decimated America, the Liberator sails
>   into a savage zombie hell
>
> U.S.S. Liberator—sailing the oceans of a nuclear-ravaged world on the
>   most dangerous mission of all... survival!
>
> A radio call for help has reached the U.S.S. Liberator from the
>   shattered metropolis of New York. Two families have somehow managed to
>   emerge unscathed from the fire and devastation of nuclear Armageddon.
>   But rescuing them may prove an impossible task. For thousands of
>   radiation-crazed "white shirts" have arisen from the ruins of the
>   once-great city for one final, savage assault on the desperate
>   survivors' stronghold—trapping Tom Donovan and his brave crew in the
>   murderous center of an unrelenting reign of zombie terror.

### Excerpt

> Welcome to my nightmare
>
> There were six corpses arranged bizarrely around the cabin. All had
>   been stripped naked. All were rotted beyond recognition, their bones
>   exposed in spots, ribbons of flesh hanging from their bodies. Two were
>   seated on the settee, one was sprawled on the top of the dinette
>   table, and two lay on the floor, their arms neatly aligned at their
>   sides, their grisly, ragged lips pulled back to expose their yellowing
>   teeth in ghastly grins of welcome.
>
> "My God," Percy declared in horror.

Comment: I think this one's a winner! I have been able to get too many details online. But the little excerpt I could find sounds familiar. Gonna have to try and get it now!

Answer (score 2):

The description is a mismatch as I am looking for the same series. The submarine was a Typhoon-class submarine that the US had purchased and turned into an underwater sea craft sub. The blue-green lasers were used as radar by the main ship as well as the mini-subs launched by it. There were underwater missiles. The story is *not* post-apocalyptic, but more a shift in global power where the US was fighting for its position. The ship was called the Sea-Wolf.

### **Update**

I think you may have conflated two books; [Stingray](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0061006157) by Bill Keith and the [Attack of the Seawolf](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0451180518) series by Michael DiMercurio.

**Stingray**

> Leviathan—the world's largest Typhoon-type vessel, a subcarrier
>   equipped with the most advanced twenty-first-century laser technology
>   and the ultimate weapon—a fast, agile fleet of SFV-4B Barracudas, the
>   undersea version of the world's hottest new fighter plane.
>
> The ultimate undersea challenge
>
> Fresh from bloody battle off the coast of Cuba, Leviathan rides out to
>   meet trouble at its source—Alexandria. There the formidable Islamic
>   navy and its allies gather, sailing through the Strait of Gibraltar to
>   block South American oil supplies and bring America to its knees.
>
> Challenged by the Teigei, a Japanese supersub whose superior
>   technology matches Leviathan's, Commander T. Morgan Gray, ace Navy
>   pilot, must lead his intrepid men into a chilling undersea battle—one
>   where only their daring, skill, and courage can snatch victory from
>   the jaws of death and devastating final defeat.

**Attack of the Seawolf**

> In the near future posited by this convincing techno-thriller, China
>   has collapsed into civil war. The U.S. nuclear sub Tampa, sent into
>   the Gulf of Chilhi to collect intelligence, is discovered and captured
>   by the communists. The Navy's newest submarine, the Seawolf, embarks
>   with a crack SEAL team for a rescue mission captained by Michael
>   Pacino, who lost his last ship in last year's Voyage of the Devilfish.
>   Now Pacino takes the Seawolf on a high-tech cutting-out expedition
>   in the best tradition of 18th-century naval warfare

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question: **what was the name of the book series?**

Comment: @randal'thor - Partial answers need love too...

Comment: @Richard And there was me about to convert this to a comment ...

Comment: @randal'thor - It's not a comment though, it's an elaboration.

Comment: Now I'm confused. Are you saying that you've conflated two different books?

Comment: [Attack of the Seawolf](http://www.amazon.com/Attack-Seawolf-Michael-DiMercurio/dp/0451180518)

Comment: [Stingray](http://www.amazon.com/Stingray-Bill-Keith/dp/0061006157)

Comment: no im saying after i did the research the two stories were crossed the Seawolf submarines are in other stories,  however they do not have the Laser technology.  that Submarine was the Leviathan. other than that the original scenario fits the previous answer about the book On the Beach.

Comment: I've tried to disambiguate what you're saying. Hopefully the OP will return to confirm which one it is (either one or both).

Comment: "*a Typhoon-class submarine that the US had purchased and turned into an underwater sea craft sub*" -- What's the difference between a submarine and an "underwater sea craft sub"?

Comment: Hey guys. Thanks for the try but no dice!

Answer (score -1):

i think it might be the Seawolf by Cristobal--i'm looking for it, too.  It was a fantasy, and part of a series, with strong female characters.

Comment: I can't find any reference to that book online. Can you provide a link and the full author's name.